# Rubyvis in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I am making a project using rails and I need to make some charts so I was thinking about using Rubyvis.

If I have the following code in the controller:

```
require 'rubyvis'

vis = Rubyvis::Panel.new do 
  width 150
  height 150

  bar do
    data [1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.5, 0.7, 0.3]
    width 20
    height {|d| d * 80}
    bottom(0)
    left {index * 25}
  end   
end

vis.render    
puts vis.to_svg
```

How should I put the output in the view?

Answer (score 1):

Generating the SVG file at runtime that you wish to display in a rendered view is not that something that should be done within the controller.

Instead, create a new method in you `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` or the helper specific to your controller action.

```
require "rubyvis"

class ApplicationHelper
  def some_method
    vis = Rubyvis::Panel.new do 
    width 150
    height 150

    bar do
      data [1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.5, 0.7, 0.3]
      width 20
      height {|d| d * 80}
      bottom(0)
      left {index * 25}
      end   
    end

    vis.render    
    vis.to_svg
  end
end
```

And now in your view you can simply call the following wherever you wish to dump the SVG data.

```
<%= some_method %>
```

Comment: +1, the answer is functionnal in itself, but i'd suggest isolating this "protovis builder" in a model rather than in a helper

Comment: it actually outputs the code itself on the screen and not the graph

Comment: You can prefix the last line with `raw`. As in `raw vis.to_svg`